# Airflow dag run prioritisation

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, python-operator

How to pick up a particular dag run which is in queued state to execution state? I want this to differentiate customers and to serve all customers without stalling them, when there are multiple requests from a single customer

I tried looking into priority weight but it's at task level but i want at dag run level

Answer (score 0):

You can separate your customers assigning them to different DAGs and then split DAGs into different [pools](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/administration-and-deployment/pools.html#concepts-pool) instead of using the default pool for all your customers.

But if you really need to prioritize DagRuns instead of DAGs, consider the following approach for your purpose:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.python import BranchPythonOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago


def decide_which_pool(**kwargs):
    return kwargs.get('params', {}).get('pool')


with DAG(
    'example_branch',
    start_date=days_ago(1),
    schedule_interval='@daily',
):

    branching = BranchPythonOperator(
        task_id='branching',
        python_callable=decide_which_pool,
        provide_context=True,
    )

    pool_1_task = BashOperator(task_id='pool_1', pool='pool_1', bash_command='echo 1')
    pool_2_task = BashOperator(task_id='pool_2', pool='pool_2', bash_command='echo 2')

    branching >> [pool_1_task, pool_2_task]
```

Then, you can pass `pool` param to your DagRun: `{"pool": "pool_1"}`

Comment: I am new to airflow could you please elaborate on implementation

Comment: @SriSai You can follow the link in my post and read the documentation. There is some sort of instruction on how you can implement it. If anything is unclear, feel free to ask.

Comment: I read through the document and a question will dag run be able to decide what pool the run should be gone based on the input parameters which are passed in conf of dag run?

Comment: @SriSai Sorry, I wrongly assumed that you divide DAGs by clients. If you want to prioritize DagRuns specifically, things become much more complex. I think this [issue](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/35803) discusses the topic you're interested in, but it hasn't been resolved yet.

Comment: @SriSai I updated original answer and suggested workaround with `BranchPythonOperator`